# sample size for normal distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, sample-size

i have a small set of data. I'm sure that their distribution is normal, with standard deviation $\sigma=10$.
I'm interested in the mean value, $\mu$ and its uncertainty. Which is the minimum sample size i must have ? And which will be the uncertainty on the mean value ? I think the uncertainty on the mean value is $\sigma_\mu=\sigma/\sqrt{N}=10/\sqrt{N}$, where $N$ is the sample size. 
Which is the min value for $N$ i should have ?
Thank you
Andrea

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use a 95% confidence interval of the form
$\bar X \pm 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n},$ where $\pm 1.96$ cut probability 2.5%
from the upper and lower tails, respectively, of the standard normal
distribution. (This leaves 95% in the central part of the distribution.)

Then. as you say the 'standard error of the mean' is $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n}.$ Also, $M = 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ is called the 'margin of
error' for the sample mean $\bar X$ as an estimate of the population mean $\mu.$

So, if you know $\sigma$ and you know what size $M$ you want, then you can solve for $n$ to get $n = (1.96\sigma/M)^2.$ It is customary to round up to
the next larger integer.